# Passing multiple parameters to Azure Durable Function

Tags: azure-durable-functions

Trying to pass multiple parameters to an Azure Durable Orchestrator function, using "short hand" tuples, from a HttpTrigger function:

```
var param1 = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
var param2 = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
// Function input comes from the request content.
string instanceId = await client.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(nameof(Function1), (param1, param2));
```

and then get them again in my Orchestrator function

```
var (param1, param2) = context.GetInput<(string, string)>();
```

however param1, and param2 are just null....
If I change the code to "normal tuples":

```
var param1 = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
var param2 = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
// Function input comes from the request content.
string instanceId = await client.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(nameof(Function1), Tupele.Create(param1, param2));
```

and

```
var (param1, param2) = context.GetInput<Tuple<string, string>>();
```

the parameters are passes correctly.

Am I doing something wrong? According to the documentation, it should be ok to use "shorthand tuple"..

```
Env:
Target framework:         net8.0
AzureFunctionsVersion     v4
Mode:                     Isolated mode
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5455 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.27.5.21554
```

Comment: I believe you cannot pass multiple parameters to the orchestrator. Hence what you did in the 2nd example if the way to go. I found this link about sending multiple parms to the activities (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-orchestrations?tabs=csharp-isolated#passing-multiple-parameters) but can't find something similar about orchestrators.

Comment: Even for ActivityTriggers it doesn't seem to work, here you also have to use:

[ActivityTrigger] Tuple<string, string> input,
and 
var (param1, param2) = input;

not that it's a bit thing, the other way would just be a lot eaiser.